# Print the index of a substring in a string in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, indexing, bin

We need to write a shell program that will tell the position (i.e index) of a substring in a given string.

Sample string:

```
Code Quotient - Get Better at Programming
```

Substring:

```
at
```

Sample output:

```
28
```

I have written the program below but it is giving `-1` in every case.

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
if [[ "$a" == "$b" ]]; then
    rest=${a#*$b}
    echo $(( ${#a} - ${#rest} - ${#b} +1 ))
else
    echo "-1"
fi
```

Comment: If you were using `zsh` instead, it's easy with its parameter expansion flags: `pos=${(SB)a#$b}` (But that won't work with `bash`)

Comment: Anyways, you're probably getting -1 because the pattern in `b` doesn't match the string in `a`. Might need `*`'s before and after... `[[ $a == *"$b"* ]]`

Comment: @Shawn : In the OPs code, there is no **pattern** match, because the right-hand side is fully quoted; hence the content of `b` is taken literally and the strings are just compared for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if both strings are equal, which of course most of the time they are not.

```sh
if [[ "$a" == "$b" ]]
```

Probably you mean

```sh
if [[ $a == *"$b"* ]]
```

where perhaps also notice that `[[` is more relaxed when it comes to quoting.

Notice also that the file's very first two bytes need to be `#!` in order for the first line to be a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)); you show yours as indented by one space, which will not work.

A better design than `read` is to accept the parameters as command-line arguments; then, the user gets the benefits of command-line history, variables, tab expansion, etc.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == *"$2"* ]]; then
    rest=${1#*$2}
    echo $(( ${#1} - ${#rest} - ${#2} +1 ))
else
    echo "-1"
fi
```

If you do use `read`, probably use `read -r`; the option disables some legacy behavior around backslashes which you basically never want to experience.

Comment: I think it should be `[[ $1 == *"$2"* ]]`, otherwise a wildcard character in `$2` would be interpreted as a pattern match.

Comment: Thanks, I was too eager to remove quoting (-: